# What's the easiest way to return the results of a query for a given key/value pair in mongo as an array of the values returned?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a field called id (not _id) in documents from two collections.  I need to compare the contents of the first collection with the second.  Basically, I need to know what documents with a given value 'id' exist in collection 'A', but not 'B'.  What's the easiest way to build an array of id's from Collection A that I can use to do something like the following. :

```
db.B.find({id:{$nin: array_of_ids_from_coll_A}})
```

Please don't get hung up over why I'm using 'id' in this case, and not '_id'.  Thanks.

Comment: mapreduce over 2 collections?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this doesn't answer the question of 'how to build an array that...', but I'd iterate over collection `A` and, for each element, try to find a match in B. If none is found, add to a list.

This has a lot of roundtrips to the database, so it's not very fast, but it's very simple. Also, if `A` contains a lot of elements, the array of ids might be too large to throw all of them in the `$nin`, which otherwise would have to be solved by splitting up the array of ids. To make matters worse, `$nin` isn't efficient with indexes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I incorrectly assumed that the function 'distinct' returned a set of distinct documents based on a given 'field'.  In fact, it returns an array of distinct values, provided a specific field.  So, I was able to construct the array I was looking for with db.A.distinct('id').  Thanks to anyone who took the time to read this question, anyway.